# What is ObjectShaderFx in bpy?

Tags: python, objects, shaders

Searching through the `bpy` hierarchy in Blender 3.3.3 I've found that objects in Blender have `shader_effects` attribute. It has `new()` method which takes 2 arguments - name (of type string) and type (of type [Shaderfx Type Items](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/object_shaderfx_type_items.html#rna-enum-object-shaderfx-type-items)). It seems quite similar to other `bpy.types.Object`'s classes, e.g. `modifiers`, `constraints`, `material_slots` etc. In those classes `new()` method increments the `len` of the class and you can access each instance by its `int` index or `str` id. But after using `new()` method in `bpy.context.object.shader_effects` nothing happens: its `len` remains 0 and no items are being added to the array.

The list of [Shaderfx Type Items](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy_types_enum_items/object_shaderfx_type_items.html#rna-enum-object-shaderfx-type-items) looks pretty intriguing: Blur, Colorize, Flip, Glow, Pixelate, Rim, Shadow, Swirl, Wave Distortion. But [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.ObjectShaderFx.html) doesn't tell much about where and how it is supposed to be used. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are the *visual effects* used by grease pencil objects. They are under the magic wand tab when you have a grease pencil object selected.

[image: Showing the available effect types in a menu in the visual effects panel for a grease pencil object]

[Manual: Grease Pencil / Visual Effects](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/grease_pencil/visual_effects/index.html)

The reason nothing happens when you used `shader_effects.new` is probably because you tried it on (eg) a mesh, not a grease pencil object. The same thing happens if you try to add a modifier to an empty for example.

If you want to try them, note that AFAICT the effects only show up in "Rendered" viewport shading, not in "Material Preview".